# Does the title "An Officer and A Gentleman" refer to one person or two?

Tags: character, title, an-officer-and-a-gentleman

There are two main actors in the movie "An Officer and A Gentleman", Richard Gere, and the other guy who committed suicide.

[image: movie poster]

Are *An Officer* and *A Gentleman* referring to the same guy, Richard Gere?

Or is one referring to Richard Gere and the other to the other guy?

Comment: The movie poster would suggest that Debra Winger is the gentleman.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it refers to one person, Zachary "Zack" Mayo (played by Gere). [As Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Officer_and_a_Gentleman):

> The film's title uses an old expression from the British Royal Navy
>   and subsequently from the U.S. Uniform Code of Military Justice, as
>   being charged with "conduct unbecoming an officer and a gentleman"
>   (from 1860).

[Matthew Sharpe explains it like this](http://cinetext.philo.at/magazine/msharpe/matthew_sharpe-what_is_the_name_of_the_father.pdf):

> At the conclusion of the film (in fulfilment of what is intimated in
>   the title) Mayo defies the odds to become an officer. Equally, he
>   honours the love of the faithful Paula, thereby proving himself a
>   gentleman.